# Determine internal format of given astc compressed image through its header?

Tags: header, webkit, opengl-es-3.0, webgl-extensions

I am writing a EbGL based HTML application that uses ASTC (Adaptive Scalable Texture Compression) compressed textures to be loaded on my triangle. I would like to know that does there exists a way to know whether the internal format of the compressed ASTC image(that in my case might be located on a remote web server) is "linear" or "srgb encoded", by parsing the ASTC header. I can then use that `internalFormat` information obtained to pass my ASTC texture to `glCompressedTexImage2D()`. In other words, for eg. I want to know whether my internal format is `COMPRESSED_RGBA_ASTC_4x4_KHR` or `COMPRESSED_SRGB8_ALPHA8_ASTC_4x4_KHR` from the header of any ASTC compressed image. Any clues?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that ASTC file header indeed doesn't fully describe its contents. It has only dimensions and some strange 'magic number' which seems to be just a constant.

Information about file header: http://malideveloper.arm.com/downloads/Stacy_ASTC_white%20paper.pdf (pages 4-5, it also refers to code samples from Mali Developer Center for more clues).

'Magic number' explained here as a mere constant value `0x5CA1AB13`:
http://community.arm.com/thread/3981

You should ask a question at Mali Developer Center forums - these guys are very helpful and usually respond quite fast.

EDIT: Header format in case external links go down:

```
struct astc_header
{
    uint8_t magic [ 4 ];
    uint8_t blockdim_x;
    uint8_t blockdim_y;
    uint8_t blockdim_z ;
    uint8_t xsize [ 3 ];
    uint8_t ysize [ 3 ];
    uint8_t zsize [ 3 ];
};
```

Comment: Thanks..I actually already posted the question at Mali Forum, but yet to receive a reply. And regarding ASTC header, it does give information about the block dimensions used, original dimensions and the magic header, but somewhere it also needs to store more info about the color coding used(srgb,linear).

Answer (score 1):

The ASTC header has no such information. You could try a file name extension, perhaps, such as .srgb.astc.   Using KTX, the Khronos alternative storage container for ASTC data, you can add key-value pair for whatever you like, though the glInternalFormat should be good enough in this case.

That said, if you store your data in the ASTC file as sRGB (non-linear gamma) then you can choose whether you want the data to be read as non-linear gamma or linear gamma by setting  COMPRESSED_RGBA_ASTC_4x4_KHR or COMPRESSED_SRGB8_ALPHA8_ASTC_4x4_KHR when you read it. That is, the sRGB-ness probably shouldn't be considered a property of the file format but a property of the texel read operation and/or your graphics pipeline. Use the appropriate kind to produce the style of output you want.