# How to set bytesPerRow parameter in replaceRegion when texture format is compressed in metal?

Tags: metal

According to [replaceRegion doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexture/1515464-replaceregion): `For a compressed pixel format, the stride is the number of bytes from the beginning of one row of blocks to the beginning of the next.`

I still don't know how to set the `bytesPerRow`. Can I get 'bytesPerRow' by given the current level of texture width and texture format? Or is there any general way of calculation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know:

- Texture Width
- Block size of your format (e.g. DXT1 is 4x4)
- Bytes per block for your format (e.g. DXT1 is 8 bytes per block).

Then the formula is something like:

```
int blocksPerRow = (textureWidth + (blockWidth - 1)) / blockWidth;
bytesPerRow = blocksPerRow * bytesPerBlock;
```

Edit: For PVRTC, don't miss this important note from `replaceRegion`

> This method is supported if you're copying to an entire texture with a PowerVR Texture Compression (PVRTC) pixel format; in which case, bytesPerRow and bytesPerImage must both be set to 0. This method isn't supported for copying to a subregion of a texture that has a PVRTC pixel format.

Comment: If I want to use ATC compressed image formats, which MTLPixelFormat should I use? It's difficult to determine which is the correct MTLPixelFormat corresponding to the compressed texture format from the name of enumeration in MTLPixleFormat.

Comment: I'm not too familiar. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600678/determine-internal-format-of-given-astc-compressed-image-through-its-header) it sounds like Mali's astc generator outputs the block size in the file header, but it does not include anything about the colour space.

Comment: Thank you. But I think ATC and ASTC are two different compressed texture format. Maybe I can post this issue at  Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Ah - I suspect ATC isn't supported by the Metal API (certainly not on iOS, but I'm less familiar with desktop)